# How remove HAProxy complain while restarting?

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

When `sudo service haproxy restart` the following message show up:

```
[WARNING] 145/113237 (6021) : config : 'option httplog' not usable with proxy 'mysql' (needs 'mode http'). Falling back to 'option tcplog'.
```

I try putting `option tcplog` in some places of the config, but the message not stop. Here my config:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen stats
        bind :8082
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /stats

listen mysql *:3307
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        option mysql-check user check
        option log-health-checks
        server db01 SERVER1:3306 check port 3306 inter 1000
        server db02 SERVER2:3306 check port 3306 inter 1000
```

Any idea how to remove that annoying message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
defaults
    log     global
    #mode    http
    #option  httplog
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option  dontlognull
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain why you think that could solve the problem? Thanks again

Comment: HAProxy has two balancing modes - http and tcp. These operate at different levels of the network stack. http deals with HTTP requests and responses. tcp deals with TCP connections between hosts. These are fundamentally different things so the type of logging possible for each is very different.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I was refering to why such config order could solve my problem, what is the parsing logic that HAProxy use with that conf file. For example, I tested putting `option tcplog` after and before the `mode tcp` line but the error still appear, when that option should overwrite the default value you are trying to comment out. I will try you proposed conf and will let you know, still are interest in what is the logic of the conf file. Thanks again.

Comment: @gsc-frank when you tried the `option tcplog` before and after `mode tcp`, did you also removed the `option httplog` and `mode http`? Later today I'll try to give you a good explanation about the parsing logic of the config file.

Comment: @borisquiroz It worked! Now my questions is, why it worked that way and not putting `mode tcp` and the `option tcplog` after the `listen mysql *:3307`. I thought that latter (or stanza scoped) directives overwrite defaults

Comment: @gsc-frank That's weird because the `mode` may be used in defaults, frontend, listen and backend sections. BUT you can only use one at a time (tcp, http or health). And your config file had `mode http` on the default section. I recommended you commented the lines related to http and replace them by a couple of lines related to tcp, which is the default on HAProxy

Comment: @borisquiroz For clarification: It worked after comment the two lines: `mode   http` and `option httplog` in the *default* section. I don't added `mode tcp` neither `option tcplog` to the default section as you suggested. Still seem to me rare that just putting `mode tcp` and `option tcplog` inside the `listen mysql` section not worked, not suppose the listen directives overwrite the defaults directives? Thanks again for all your support.

Comment: @gsc-frank when you put `mode tcp` and `option tcplog` inside the `listen` section, did you removed `mode http` and `option httplog` from the config file?

Answer (score 2):

rather than change the entire global config... you're better off by adding the line `option tcplog` to the particular `listen` block you're concerned with

[as per the documentation.](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/)

> The option httplog setting, or more rarely option tcplog, tells
> HAProxy to use a more verbose log format when sending messages to
> Syslog. **You will generally prefer `option httplog` over `option tcplog` in
> your `defaults` section because when HAProxy encounters a `frontend` that
> uses `mode tcp`, it will emit a warning and downgrade it to `option tcplog` anyway.**

```
listen mysql *:3307
        mode tcp
        option tcplog #add this line
        balance roundrobin
        option mysql-check user check
        option log-health-checks
        server db01 SERVER1:3306 check port 3306 inter 1000
        server db02 SERVER2:3306 check port 3306 inter 1000
```